# how to append block of file to another file

Tags: java, android

I have a requirement that I need to append block of a file to other file.

let say I have 100 lines in source file and I need to append the 50 lines from the bottom to destination file.

To navigate to the 50th line I using .readLine() of the BufferedReader.

Once I reached to 50 th line I want to append remaining content to the destination file.
I don't want to append line by line as it is consuming much time.

Please help me how to do that..

Please provide a code snippet if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read the file line by line and append in StringBuffer object

for eg

```
StringBuffer lineBuffer = new StringBuffer();
String line = "";

while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
///// any condition or anything you want to do
     lineBuffer.append(line);
}
```

now after you get the lines into the stringbuffer object write this into another file